# I was writing a menu driven program to find the volume of some shapes. However, there is a problem in the calculation of sphere's volume. Pls help me

Tags: java

The formula for volume of a sphere is 4/3 intio 3.14 into radius into radius into radius. In my program I have used this formula only but in the calculation for the volume, the 4/3 is omitted. It only multiplies 3.14 with radius cubed. Here is the code

[part 1 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNlhJ.png)

[part 2 of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBsAz.png)

In the output, 4/3 is not getting multiplied. Only 3.14 is multiplied with radius cube. Any reason why the multiplication with 4/3 is getting omitted? If so, what is the fix?

Comment: I know the way I have displayed my question and code might be inconvenient, so I apologise. I tried copy pasting the code, but it said I had to indent it and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!!. You can use the code option available in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is doing integer algebra, instead, you should have used floats. Since both `4` and `3` are integers, the value of `4/3` comes out to be `1`.

Use the float value here like `4.0/3.0` works.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. This is correct.